# How to combine file upload and submit forms values together

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" class="email">
    <input type="text" placeholder="LINK TO REEL/BREAKDOWNS" class="reel">
    <input type="text" placeholder="SKILLSETS" class="skill">
    <input type="text" placeholder="SALARY REQUIREMENTS" class="salary">
    <p>Upload Your Resume (pdf only)</p>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="APPLY" name="submit">
</form>
```

How can I use jQuery to validate the fields and upload the file using ajax. My backend is php.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/hyj2bpad/

Comment: are u trying to upload the file using ajax ..??

Comment: I am looking for a way to upload file as well as submit my form values in one click. I am not expecting anyone to write complete code. I guess I do have some tech knowledge. Thanks. Have a good day

Comment: if u use ajax then you have to create formData object and pass that via ajax data . it will show all form data as well file uploaded data on submit form .....

Comment: Thanks @Affan let me try that :)

Answer (score 1):

for the front-end form validate you can try:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

but, please also keep in mind that, you NEED ANOTHER validation for the server side ;)

Comment: Thank you. I want to know how to submit both form values and upload the file in one shot.

Comment: you just need to wrap all your info into a `FormData` object. validate, if valid, send it.other wise, stop

Answer (score 1):

hint to use formData

```
 var t_formdata = new formData(); //this will bind entire form (also upload data)
 url : 'your url',
 data:t_formdata,
 success:function(){
 }
```

if u not use formData it will show only data not file part

for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects